# Click on dynamically created HTML elements using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to be able to click on a element I've dynamically created and create an alert, and I can't seem to figure it out.  I've looked at a bunch of similar threads on how to use .on, but I can only get it to work for static elements.  Thanks in advance!

```
<span id="about">About</span>

<div id="lhn"></div>
```

And JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#about").click(function () {

        $("#lhn").append("<div id='#child'>Child</div>");

        $("#lhn").on("click", "#child", function () {
            alert("Child has been clicked");
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: switching the order did it, thanks everyone!  And sorry about the ID typo, good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind the event outside your `about` click handler. also, your ID should be `child` not `#child` when creating the element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#lhn").on("click", "#child", function () {
        alert("Child has been clicked");
    });

    $("#about").click(function () {
        $("#lhn").append("<div id='child'>Child</div>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple issues with the code that you have written.

**Firstly**

```
$("#lhn").append("<div id='#child'>Child</div>");
```

supposed to be

```
$("#lhn").append("<div id='child'>Child</div>");
```

**Secondly - ID's in a HTML page are supposed to be unique**

So replace

```
$("#lhn").append("<div id='child'>Child</div>");
```

with

```
$("#lhn").append("<div class='child'>Child</div>");
```

**Third**

I see you are already delegating the event, so move the click event to outside the `click event` . Otherwise **events will be bound multiple times to the element on every click**.

```
$("#about").click(function () {
    $("#lhn").append("<div class='child'>Child</div>");
});

$("#lhn").on("click", ".child", function () {
    alert("Child has been clicked");
});
```

Comment: If I'm only appending one child, wouldn't I still want to use an ID rather than a class?

Comment: If it's only a single element then you can go with an `ID`

Comment: Cool.  Still learning, wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

One technique I use for appending elements is to create the element, then append it.

```
var element = $("<div id='child'>Child</div>").appendTo("#lhn").on("click", function() {
    alert("Child has been clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

user this simple code,

```
$("#child).live("click",function(){
    alert();
});
```